# Testing criteria creation in a Grails service

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a Grails service that creates a criteria query with optional parameters like this:

```
List<Car> search(String make = "%", String model = "%", Integer year = null) {
    def c = Car.createCriteria()

    return c.list() {
        if(make) {
            like("make", make)
        }
        if(model) {
            like("model", model)
        }
        if(year) {
            eq("year", year)
        }
    }
}
```

(Also, is this the idiomatic way to do this in grails? I'm quite new to the framework and I'm trying to find the right way to do things)

I'd like to test that the proper criteria filters are set according to the values of the parameters of the `search` method but I'm having no success.

I tried some variations of this:

```
@TestFor(CarService)
@Mock(Car)
class CarServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def car = Mock(Car)
    void "empty filters"() {
        when: service.search()
        then:
        with(car.createCriteria()) {
            0 * like(*_)
            0 * eq(*_)
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to find a way to do assertions about the interactions between the `CarService` and the criteria object.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should be using an integration test

Comment: You don't really want to test if Criteria work... you want to test if the criteria you've built will find what you want.  Create some fake Cars, then run the method by passing in some parameters, and see if the right Cars result.

Comment: @billjamesdev this sounds weird. By doing an actual query and executing it i'd be actually testing the criteria class, while what i want to test is that the object is created correctly and that the expected methods are invoked on it. I was actually looking for a way to avoid a full-fledged integration test, since this logic is not depending on the persistence layer.

Comment: @Raibaz if you build your test inputs correctly, your results should show whether you built the criteria correctly, you don't need to see each individual  internal call happen.  Note, you also have unnecessary conditions (or default values).. if the default value is "%", you don't need the condition wrapper, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grails Where query instead of the Criteria query seems to be better choice for an idiomatic way to do this in Grails:

[Gorm Where Query](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#whereQueries)